# Inverse of elementary functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inverse

which may be two right inverse of:

1) $h:\Re \rightarrow [0,\infty) $ defined by $h(x)=|x|$

2) $k:\Re \rightarrow [1,\infty)$ defined by $k(x)= e^{x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

1). The inverse is $h^{-1}(x)=x$

2). The inverse is $k^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{\ln x}$

Comment: Yes, but the book they asks me to find  two right inverses for each one...

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread. Do you already know what the identity element is?

Comment: Yes, if h has right and left reverse, then there is inverse function h^-1. I'm interested in how to get the right and left inverse..